# CSS Media Query loading

Tags: css, media-queries

If I have a CSS media query as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:1024px)" href="css/ipad.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:1024px)" href="css/desktop.css">
```

I see that it loads both the CSS desktop.css and ipad.css

This is the case even if I change the min/max-width to min/max-device-width

Why is this so AND how do I ensure that only the relevant CSS gets loaded ?

Comment: What browser / device are you targeting? Oh and close your link tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say, it's normal that the browser loads both files. But it should apply only one style. What happens to you, are both styles applied, or only one?

You could also work with the orentation parameter btw.

Comment: It applies correctly..my question was why does it load both of them!

Comment: Because it's the normal behaviour a browser works. Even a CSS file which is only for printing will be auto loaded, but only applied when a user switches to print view.